# Failed to extract the data recieved by POST

Tags: zig

I'm trying to write an API that is recievig JSON data, I was able to rcieve the data, but not sure how can I read it or extract its contents.
My code line is:

```
pub fn post(response: *http.Server.Response) void {
    response.do() catch |e| {
        std.log.err("{any}", .{e});
    };
    if (response.request.method != .HEAD) {
        std.log.debug("Prenting request details", .{});
        std.log.info("{any}", .{response.request});
    }
}
```

I sent the `curl` command `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/post -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"login":"my_login", "password":"my_password"}'`
And the output I got is:

```
debug: Prenting request details
info: http.Server.Request{ .method = http.Method.POST, .target = { 47, 112, 111, 115, 116 }, .version = http.Version.HTTP/1.1, .content_length = 46, .transfer_encoding = null, .transfer_compression = null, .headers = Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 46
, .parser = http.protocol.HeadersParser{ .state = http.protocol.State.finished, .header_bytes_owned = true, .header_bytes = array_list.ArrayListAlignedUnmanaged(u8,null){ .items = { ... }, .capacity = 165 }, .max_header_bytes = 8192, .next_chunk_length = 0, .done = true }, .compression = http.Server.Compression{ .none = void } }
```

How can I read the JSON data from this response? and as a validation point, how can I check the `Content-Type`, I can see it in the response but no idea how to handle it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the request body from a [`reader`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:http.Server.Response.reader) on `std.http.Server.Response`:

```
const max_size = 8192;
const body = try response.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, max_size);
defer allocator.free(body);
```